# WSO2 json response variable convert with xslt

Tags: wso2-esb

I just started working with *Wso2*

I want to convert JSON response variables to camelCase.

I can show examples with **Xslt**

Comment: Please show examples with **Xslt**

Comment: Please elaborate. Could you give an example of a message or content that you want to convert to camelcase?